# How can i add another class to elements only if they are more than two on page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I simulate a game of cards - you can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cvw69/7/) As i turn them i toggle a class 'back' to them and their background image is given by a common id. As you see after you turn two of them they turn back down. But i would like to keep them turned if they have the same image.
And in any manner i would try i cannot figure how to use the length of a combination like

```
if($('.back.#i1').length==2) {do smth}
```

to remove the class 'face' that make them click-able.

Comment: The selector `.back.#i1` is invalid. [Class names cannot start with `#`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier).

Comment: You should not depend on multiple elements having the same id.  Why not use [**data attributes**](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) instead, which are supported by [**`jQuery.data`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method?

Comment: *"...and their background image is given by a common id."* Huh?

Comment: Also you should consider separating the presentation logic from the control logic.  The way you're making program logic depend on HTML properties will become fragile as your application becomes more complicated. i.e., have a model for your cards, like an array, that you process instead of the actual display elements.

Comment: another case of http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#adef-id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at your code and posted a working version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WkTMr/2/)
As the previous post pointed out, you want to make sure your elements have unique ids or else you face problems when trying to locate them. so something like this:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="i1" class="card face" cardFace="image1"></div>
  <div id="i2" class="card face" cardFace="image2"></div>
  <div id="i3" class="card face" cardFace="image1"></div>
  <div id="i4" class="card face" cardFace="image2"></div>
</div>
```

I updated your css and the logic in your code to work with these divs.
What the code now does is on the initial element click it saves what cardface it has itno a variable, then it sets the div to have a back class and a class that represents the image once the first animation completes

```
var myCardface = $(this).attr("cardFace");
...
//Toggle card back status
$(this).toggleClass('back');
// Set the image to be shown
$(this).toggleClass('back_'+myCardface);
```

At the end of the second animation, the code now looks for all cards that are showing their back (excluding the current one) and checks to see if they have the same "cardFace" value.If they do it marks both of them as done.

```
//Check for other open cards having the same cardFace value
$("#content").find(".back").not("#"+$(this).attr("id")).each(function(index){
if(myCardface == $(this).attr("cardFace")){
  matchFound = true;
  $(this).toggleClass('done');
}

if(matchFound == true){
  $(this).toggleClass('done');
}
```

If two cards have been turned on the back, the code will then flip those back so that they don't remain open.

```
var unmatchedCards = $('.back:not(.done)').length
//Reset the cards
if(unmatchedCards == 2){
  $('.back:not(.done)').each(function(){
    $(this).animate({
      rotateY: "+=" + (Math.PI) / 2
    }, 500, function() {
      //Toggle card back status
      $(this).toggleClass('back');
      // Set the image to be shown
      $(this).toggleClass('back_'+$(this).attr("cardFace"));
    }).animate({
      rotateY: "+=" + (Math.PI) / 2
    }, 500);
  });
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it will solve all of your problems but your use of IDs is not the best:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="i1" class="card face"></div>
    <div id="i2" class="card face"></div>
    <div id="i1" class="card face"></div>
    <div id="i2" class="card face"></div>
</div>
```

You should be using classes:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="i1 card face"></div>
    <div class="i2 card face"></div>
    <div class="i1 card face"></div>
    <div class="i2 card face"></div>
</div>
```